# Why am I no longer allowed to delete comments on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, comments

I added a comment to a post, but now the post was updated and my comment no longer applies, so I would like to delete it. I was able to delete comments some days ago, today I noticed this is no longer supported. Is it intentional?

Comment: I can still delete comments, maybe you need specific privileges?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete comments that you own. There is a little delete 'x' button right next to them.

You may run into an issue if you are no longer signed into the same account (since you appear to be 'unknown' here as well).

Email team@stackoverflow.com to get your accounts merged and the problem fixed.

Comment: Yes, that was so before ;) But today I published some comments, and I don't have this button any longer.

Comment: Ah! I think you hit the nail on the head there concerning not being signed in to the same account.

Comment: At meta.stackoverflow.com I have the button, but not at stackoverflow.com

Comment: @unknown: Again, contact the team. You are not logging in properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to delete comments by hitting the X on the right side of your comment. The only thing I can think of is if you somehow do not have the rep anymore to be able to post comments (which I imagine would prevent you from also deleting old ones?).

**Edit** Rich B stated it first in his answer, but I am going to update my answer as well to include the new information.

If you are using an "unknown" account, it is likely that your credentials are not the same as when you posted the comment, so the system is not treating you as if you are the owner of the comment. If that is the case you need to inform the StackOverflow team at team@stackoverflow.com and they will be able to help you get all your different accounts straightened out, which should give you back ownership of your comments.

Comment: Why should not I suddenly not have the rep? This is my account at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/users/98693/ovanes

Comment: If you have an account on SO, why are you not using the same account here?

Comment: I used google-id to log-in. Tried to login here asked me for the open-id again, so I signed in again and become unknown. I remember there was a statement, that this relates to how google open-id is assigned... Thanks a lot. Before going here I did use the open-id at serverfault.com, but that did not cause such problems before. May be that is because I deleted one of my closed posts today???

Comment: Once more: email team@stackoverflow.com with details. They can fix you up.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. The problem was that my browser somehow failed to load the icon. I found it when looked at my posts marked with check-marks. There I saw:

```
checked
```

Instead of check-mark image. Unfortunately the delete icon did not have the alternative text, and so it was not visible at all. After hitting Ctrl+F5 all icons were there and I was able to remove the comment.

Maybe the team members of StackOverflow should consider changing the alt-text to the delete icon as well.

Comment: It's great that you got it working. Since this was a transient issue, I think I'll close the post as "no longer relevant".

Comment: out of curiosity what browser were you using?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 3.5 @ Win XP 32bit